# New to ClickOnce. What to enter as Instalation Folder URL?

Tags: clickonce

I added ClickOnce to my application. I have a ftp server where I want to publish my app. And I also have a website, where the download should happen. 
What's the use of entering this website to the Instalation Folder URL?

And also, after publishing what should I make available for download? Setup.exe? Or the ".application" file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. So if you have something like ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/App/ for the Publishing Folder, you'd want a http:// page for the Instalation URL.